# Vector format logos of SE sites?

Tags: support, logo

There are vector logos for five of the sites: https://stackoverflow.com/company/logos.

I was wondering if there were also vector logos for the other sites that are available for download? (I am looking, in particular, for Mathematics, but ideally I'd like them all!)

Edit: Thanks to IBUG's answer, I've gotten a few of them and can share these few logos in SVG and PDF format - [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11hgeTsfbZu3lRRpgjrhkudKFIqNtnUZF).

Unfortunately I don't know any programming and this takes me a bit of work. Hopefully someone else who knows better can easily get them all and share all of them with everybody.

Comment: ah, wait, the sprites.svg do contain the logo as well, you just have to do some work to extract them.

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on the logo and hit "Inspect", you'll see it's part of an SVG image on `cdn.sstatic.com`.

I'll expand this answer when I get to my computer later.

Comment: Sadly, most of the logos haven't been SVG-ified yet :(

Comment: Did you ever get back to your computer? :P